# How to build Qt Ruby/ruby-KDE/Qt Bindings on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, qt, kde-plasma, qtruby

Does anyone know where I can check out the latest source code of http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Ruby
and how I can build it on Windows?

I would like to build the latest version against Qt 4.8

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is already a binary of Qt bindings for Ruby released as `qtbindings` gem:

RubyGems:

http://rubygems.org/gems/qtbindings

Source repository:

https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings

On the source, it also cover what are the requirements for building it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The documentation is incomplete for building it on Windows. The binary Gem is built against an old version of Qt 4.6 -- currently 4.8 is the latest

Comment: @denysonique open an issue and get in touch with gem author, that is the way to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Installation of [Qtbindings](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings) is quick and easy:

```
C:\Users\somebody>gem install qtbindings

Fetching: qtbindings-qt-4.8.6-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed qtbindings-qt-4.8.6-x86-mingw32
Fetching: qtbindings-4.8.6.2-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed qtbindings-4.8.6.2-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for qtbindings-qt-4.8.6-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for qtbindings-qt-4.8.6-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for qtbindings-4.8.6.2-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for qtbindings-4.8.6.2-x86-mingw32
Done installing documentation for qtbindings-qt, qtbindings after 4 seconds
2 gems installed

C:\Users\somebody>
```

This assumes that ruby is already installed. Note that it might be necessary to set the path to the ruby binaries first, in case that the Ruby installer omitted that. This depends on your installation. Do not copy and paste blindly:

```
set PATH=C:\Ruby22\bin;%PATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

As reported by @bogl, this answer is outated:

New repository for qtruby is https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdebindings/ruby/qtruby/repository (and for korundum: https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdebindings/ruby/korundum/repository)

Comment: These repositories are outdated, unfortunately. Maintained source is available in qtbindings on github.